# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
doesn't exist. I've tried different paths like $(x,y)=(t^2,t)$, and everything seems to work fine but the term $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in the denominator. Do you know some other useful composition for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along $x=y^{2}$ (which is same as the one you tried) the limit is $\infty$. Since the limit along $x=0$ is $0$ the limit does not exist as a finite or infinite limit.

Comment: Ok, I understood my mistake. After many similar exercises, I was hoping that, given the new path, the limit would not remain in terms of a variable (I expected a constant). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take path $(t^5, t^2)$, then

$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{t^5 t^4}{(t^{10} + t^8)\sqrt{t^{10}+t^4} } = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{t^9}{t^{10} (t^2+1)\sqrt{t^6 + 1}} = \infty.$